# Categorising consumers using segment data, using json format

Tags: python, json, segment

I have a json data for segments like following:
{"Segment_definitions":[{"segmentName":"S1","definition":{"a1":[19.0,25.0],"a2":["Seg2"]}},{"segmentName":"S2","definition":{"a4":[true,false],"a3":[4,6],"a1":[-1.0,21.0]}}]}

This is the deciding json data for categorisation.

Consumer examples -

1. {"a1":{"type":"Double","value":21.0},"a2":{"type":"string","value":"Seg1"},"a3":{"type":"Int","value":5},"a4":{"type":"Boolean":"value":false}}
2. {"a1":{"type":"Double","value":2.0},"a2":{"type":"string","value":"Seg2"},"a3":{"type":"Int","value":-1},"a4":{"type":"Boolean":"value":true}}

I need to categorise these 2 consumers into S1 or S2 segments.
The code needs to be  scalable to add further segments in the future.
How do i do that using json arrays expicitly?

I have tried converting to dataframe and tried to compare row by row but the code was too tedious.

Comment: What defines whether a customer is in each segment?

Comment: the json with "segment definitions" are the conditions that a consumer data needs to pass to be classified into that particular segment. I have given 2 consumer data as examples to test